# Why does maven ignore versions of compile transitive dependencies defined in test dependency

Tags: maven, selenium, serenity-bdd

I have the following test dependencies in a maven project where serenity.version is set to 2.0.30

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core/2.0.30) all the selenium dependencies of serenity-core-2.0.30 are set to 3.141.59

Running `mvn -U dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.seleniumhq.selenium` outputs the following

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ core ---
[INFO] <snip>
[INFO] \- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:jar:2.0.30:test
[INFO]    \- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:2.0.30:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.141.59:test
[INFO]       |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]       \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.29.3:test
```

I have to add the following dependencies to avoid runtime errors - why is version 3.9.1 being used and how do I avoid this?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<dependencyManagement>` section in your pom that sets or imports versions for selenium?

Comment: That is the issue, indirectly via the spring-boot parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE sets the property selenium.version to 3.9.1 and lists all but the selenium-server artifact in it's dependencyManagement section - setting `selenium.version` in my POM fixed the issue.